# Можете обьяснить, что делает @bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telebot

Делаю своего первого бота на PyTelegramBotAPI. Столкнулся с функцией callback, в частности

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def handler_call(call):
    chatID = call.message.chat.id
    message_id = call.message.message_id
    username = call.from_user.first_name
    pay = 'opl' + str(chatID)
    send_requests = f""
    buy1 = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=3)
    buy1.add(
        types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Оплатить', url=send_requests, callback_data='pay')
    )
```

Никак не могу понять что она делает, можете пожалуйста объяснить(желательно простым языком)

Больше всего меня интересует для чего нужен этот хендлер и что означает Что означает func=lambda call: True

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
```

Comment: Это называется ленивым хендлером, который впитывает в себя любые колбеки, по нормальному вместо `True` писать какое-то условие типа `call.data == 'any_call_data'`